# Do I need to host ASP.NET Core API on a web server to join it on Production environment?

Tags: c#, .net-core, api-design, production-environment

I've got an API that I'm running on a raspberry, I configured the application to listen on a port of this machine which I'm sending HTTP requests on with my PC on the same local network with :

`http://<raspberry-ip>:<configured-port>/<api-route>`

Everything is working as I think I intended to when I do `dotnet run` on my raspberry (launches on Dev environment).

Now I want to consume this API with a desktop app either with Windows form or Avalonia (but this is irrelevant here). Before working on my client desktop app on my PC I wanted to deploy the app on my raspberry to launch it on boot, that's where trouble began.

The API now listen on localhost:5000 as it's now on Production environment, so it works locally (can do HTTP requests on my raspberry) but I cannot join it from my PC.

I didn't know how to configure the port on which my raspberry is intended to listen on Production environment and I failed to find it, I'm even wondering if that is possible. I came across this article on [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=linux-ubuntu) to build a web server as an interface between my API and HTTP request from my PC (as I understand it).

Is this the only way to do this or can I use a custom port in Production too to join directly my raspberry with `http://<raspberry-address>:<custom-port>` ?

Comment: Have you tried calling the API with tools such as Postman from your desktop PC?  If you can't access it, then it is probably a firewall/network issue, so you need to check for the firewall on your Rpi (if enabled) and the settings on your router.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I did test my API on Dev env with insomnia and everything is working as itended, I already took care of firewall issues. The problem is mainly that my Production app is lauching on localhost:5000 on my raspberry while on Prod env. Many thanks for responding to me !

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change the Kestrel Endpoints in the `appsettings.json` file.

```
"Kestrel": {
      "Endpoints": {
        "Http": {
          "Url": "http://<raspberry>:<port>"
          }
        }
      }
```

Here is some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0) about this. And some explanations about [reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/when-to-use-a-reverse-proxy?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for people like me who may have the same questions.